# How can I create an object in TypeScript with a constrained generic value type?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, inheritance

I know that key/value objects in TypeScript are typed like this:

```js
const animals: { [key: string]: string } = { a1: "cat", a2: "dog" };
```

The above object only allows values of type string.

Now, let's say I have this abstract class

```js
abstract class Animal {
  abstract makeSound(): void;

  move(): void {
    console.log("roaming the earth...");
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that my `animals` object can only have actual animals, i.e. classes (not instances) that extends `Animal`?

I've tried this, but get "cannot find name 'T'" as an error.

```js
const animals: { [key: string]: T extends typeof Animal } = { a1: Cat, a2: Dog };

const animal = new animals["a2"]();
```

Also tried this, but get "'?' expected"

```js
const animals: { [key: string]: any extends typeof Animal } = { a1: Cat, a2: Dog };

const animal = new animals["a2"]();
```

If I knew all types of animals beforehand (but I don't) this would work:

```js
const animals: { [key: string]: typeof Cat | typeof Dog } = { a1: Cat, a2: Dog };

const animal = new animals["a2"]();
```

Is there a way to make this generic?

Comment: Doesn't `{ [key: string]: typeof Animal }` work for you? Also you could write it nicer as `Record<string, typeof Animal>`

Comment: @AlexChashin That would work only if you cast e.g. `animals["a2"]` to `any` first before trying to create an instance, since otherwise the compiler would complain about `Animal` being abstract.

Comment: So if you're fine with making `Animal` non-abstract `{ [key: string]: typeof Animal }` should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments above, it seems OP may be asking whether one can create a map of classes that all extend Animals (rather than a map of Animal instances).  That can be done using a function and generics, like so [Edited to address the comment below]:

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract makeSound(): void;

  move(): void {
    console.log("roaming the earth...");
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  makeSound(){console.log("meow")}
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  makeSound(){console.log("woof")}
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
  makeSound(){console.log(“roar”)}
}

function addToAnimals<T extends Record<string, typeof Animal>, U extends Record<string, type of Animal>(animals: T | {}, newAnimal: U){
  return {...animals, ...newAnimal}
}

const animals = addToAnimals({}, {a :Dog, b: Cat})
const animals2 = addToAnimals(animals, {c: Tiger})

const animal = new animals["a"]();
const animal2 = new animals2[“c”]();
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAKAQVEhngUIGsBTAZQHsBXbAEwAoBKAFwIAbm1zcA3GQr02IpgOFiJpWZVhtsYNsiYA6ZGwDmvAERQ2wfLmzGEEABZMETYFCf6vZ-tMoBfMkCyFDQMAGFgRCYADwgmHgwcAiI1SkZWTh4BEk1tXQMjUzN8JjYAdx9A4ND0BAARE1c4hO4kvEJicnTgZnYuPn5crR09QxNzcrY2ADMqoJlajAAVXGMmKGb4xKwO1O76XsyBgVI80cKJiysoeeCZrnhcLSpubmW2ZM6wAB5lrdaGAASkxNFBuD8aLZjAAaBwATwADmUZrsUsgAHxwgCqAJ2ILBEKhdjhECRKLRnQxGN4wD2yDAwmWcOwTHKXyIwmxQ1kUCYEA4UGwpC8%20jp6LAcNFrPZ9OqixGiHF3wQAF5Xu9PvSwLwSP44SRgAhBI1YQgQMJIhB-PwFdoldqAExqjUfDkM2nag2wJlrDY2mQhRVUekumUhiUAbTMIDMAF0BNJzg70c71eHlUQwI7o7B44mgA)

The basic idea is that the creator function takes in the new extended class with a constraint `<T extends Record<string, typeof Animal>>` which insures you are only giving it Animals.  But TS then infers the actual class value from the parameter and uses it when it builds the new animals object.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to use this. I tried adding a `class Tiger extends Animal` and then doing `const animals2 = addToAnimals(animals, {c: Tiger})`, but then I get a compilation error "Argument of type '{ c: typeof Tiger; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: typeof Dog; b: typeof Cat; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type '{ a: typeof Dog; b: typeof Cat; }'"

Comment: A bigger problem though, is that I can't do `new animals[someStringVariable]();`. I get "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: typeof Dog; b: typeof Cat; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ a: typeof Dog; b: typeof Cat; }'."

Comment: On your first point, you are right, I messed up the typing of the function a bit.  I will edit the answer to fix.  On the second, is the value of someStringVariable known at compile time?

Comment: If you try to do `var someStringVariable = “b” you will get the error you note if you call `new animals[someStringVariable]()` because the type is widened to a string.  But you can avoid that by using `var someStringVariable = “b” as const` to avoid type widening.

Answer (score 1):

When writing my comment I didn't notice the abstract thing, so sorry for that.

Anyway, I don't think it's possible to do what you want. Basically your question reduces to "Is there a way to make a type, that includes all children of a given class which are not abstract?", to do this, given a class, you would need to check whether it's abstract or not, which is impossible. So the only option you have, as I see, is to either make `Animal` not abstract, or just go without types in this place.

Also `typeof` will not work, if `Animal` is abstract, because imagine you find a way to make a type `ChildrenOf<T>`, which includes all children of a class, but not the class itself. If `Animal` is normal, it's fine, but if `Animal` is abstract, then you can do this:

```
abstract class Mammal extends Animal {}

const a: ChildrenOf<Animal> = Mammal
new a()
```

Here `Mammal` is assignable to `ChildrenOf<Animal>`, because it's a child, but it's abstract, so it's not supposed to be instanciated. This problem doesn't appear if `Animal` is normal, because then `Mammal` is not assignable to `typeof Animal`

Comment: You are correct. I did think of this scenario, but still thought it would be more useful/helpful than just going with `any` as the type... But yeah, subclasses that are themselves abstract are going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here.  To your main question, when you define an an abstract class (or any class for that matter), you are also defining a type in typescript.  So to then restrict a type to that class, e.g., Animal, you simply have to use it's name.  So `[key:string]: Animal`

There are a few other issues here in that you are instantiating Cat and Dog without calling constructors and then instantiating an array with a constructor.  Here's what I think is the cleaned up code you want:

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract makeSound(): void;

  move(): void {
    console.log("roaming the earth...");
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  makeSound(){console.log("meow")}
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  makeSound(){console.log("woof")}
}

const animals: { [key: string]: Animal } = { a1: new Cat, a2: new Dog };

const animal = animals["a2"];
```

And a playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAKAQVEhngUIGsBTAZQHsBXbAEwAoBKAFwIAbm1zcA3GQr02IpgOFiJpWZVhtsYNsiYA6ZGwDmvAERQ2wfLmzGEEABZMETYFCf6vZ-tMoBfMkCyFDQMAGFgRCYADwgmHgwcAiI1SkZWTh4BEk1tXQMjUzN8JjYAdx9A4ND0BAARE1c4hO4kvEJicnTgZnYuPn5crR09QxNzcrY2ADMqoJk8yCoOojBhEgQAbWYAT2EaW2MAXWFkzoR-BABeUioARmFsJnKESIgAGioAJieXhqa-mkIRGiGAq2It3BKWQYC2ZmA3zMx0kQA).

Comment: I think you missunderstood what OP wants. `animals` should not be a map of `Animal` instances, but a map of types that extend `Animal` so you can create an instance of a specific subtype dynamically.

Comment: OP's question was "How can I make it so that my animals object can only have actual animals, i.e. classes that extends Animal?"  But I see how the code that follows could fit your interpretation. OP, could you perhaps clarify (or, if it's just me who misunderstands, ignore...)

Comment: I've provided an alternate answer below to this version of the question, which as I read it over, I tend to agree with @sloth that is what OP is asking.